# vue-browserify import yaml file as javascript object vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, yaml, browserify

I use vuejs2 with browserify (https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify)

I try to play with YAML file

I want to try different ways to import my .yml file:

**1) Directly import like a json file. So I don't have to provide yaml file in production:**

```
import Data from '../static/data.yml'
```

**2) Import from external url (So i can change data on the app without having to rebuild):**

**3) Convert YML to JSON on save**

Actually in found a lot of solution with webpack but not with browserify

There is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vuejs-browserify-yaml",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "John DOE <john.doe@gmail.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/build.js",
    "serve": "http-server -o -c 1 -a localhost",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -p [ vueify/plugins/extract-css -o dist/build.css ] -e src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "browserify-hmr": "^0.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^2.0.0",
    "envify": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^5.3.5",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^1.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.3.0",
    "proxyquireify": "^3.0.1",
    "uglify-js": "^2.5.0",
    "vueify": "^9.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spend a lot of time on various forum i found a solution

**1) Directly import like a json file. So I don't have to provide yaml file in production:**

First install yamlify

```
npm install --save-dev yamlify
```

Then add yamlify to browserify transform

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "vueify",
      "yamlify"
    ]
  },
```

And finaly import your YAML as a classic json file (in main.js for example)

```
import Data from '../static/example-data.yml'
```

**2) Import from external url**

First install yamljs

```
npm install --save-dev yamljs
```

And then you can get external file data like that

```
import YAML from 'yamljs'
const ExternalData = YAML.load('http://localhost:8080/static/example-data.yml')
console.log(ExternalData)
```

**3) Convert YML to JSON on save**
First install yamljs

```
npm install --save-dev yamljs
```

Then update scripts on package.json (add yml2json and update watchify)

```
"scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/build.js | npm run yaml2json",
    "yaml2json": "yaml2json static -r -s -w",
    "serve": "http-server -o -c 1 -a localhost",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -p [ vueify/plugins/extract-css -o dist/build.css ] -e src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js"
  },
```